# Que veut dire "master en cours d’accréditation" ?

Tags: sens

J'ai remarqué dans le titre d'un master : « *master en cours d’accréditation* »

Que veut dire *l’accréditation d'un master* ?
Cela veut-il dire que le master n'est pas encore valable ?

Comment: N'est-ce pas une possible confusion avec l'expression "en cours d'*acquisition*" ?

Comment: non, c’est bien cours d’accréditation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Que l'ouverture de cette formation dépend de l'autorisation accordée ou pas par les autorités supérieures (ministère, université, etc).

Pour cela les établissements qui veulent ouvrir un master doivent déposer un dossier qui explique

- l'intérêt qu'il y a à ouvrir cette formation (débouchés)
- les contenus qui y seront enseignés
- sur quelles équipes d'enseignants la formation va s'appuyer
- les liens avec la recherche
- etc.

Ce dossier est, supposons, étudié avec soin par les autorités universitaires et ministérielles qui décident si il est possible de lancer cette formation telle qu'elle est décrite. Ou pas. C'est l'accréditation.

Mais l'histoire ne s'arrête pas là. Décider d'ouvrir une formation est une chose, encore faut-il avoir les conditions pour le faire. En particulier, *il faut avoir assez d'inscrits* pour que ça ne soit pas un gouffre financier. Qu'une formation tourne avec 25 étudiants ou 3, c'est le même coût, mais pas la même *rentabilité*.  Pour mettre des enseignants sur cette formation, il faut payer quelqu'un pour faire les cours qu'ils assuraient ailleurs...

Parce que, si vous ouvrez par exemple une formation en 2 ans, et que vous n'avez que 3 étudiants inscrits en première année d'ouverture, l'année suivante la situation sera encore plus difficile parce qu'il faudra ouvrir aussi la seconde année dans des conditions très déficitaires. Sans garantie d'en avoir davantage en premiere année.

Dans de telles circonstances, la formation accréditée peut ne pas ouvrir par manque de candidats. C'est une décision de bonne gestion des fonds (publics ou pas). Ca arrive assez souvent.

Donc par précaution, la campagne d'annonce de la formation, de recrutement, etc. est lancée très en amont, pour s'assurer qu'il y aura suffisamment de candidats pour "remplir" raisonnablement la première année. Sans savoir à ce stade si la formation sera accréditée. Ce n'est pas en août qu'on va annoncer une formation pour septembre.

C'est pour cette raison que les documents précisent "master sous réserve d'accréditation". On devrait aussi préciser  "et ouverture sous réserve d'un nombre suffisant d'inscrits", comme pour les excursions touristiques.

Comment: Pour moi l'accréditation ne concerne pas tant l'autorisation d'ouverture, que la reconnaissance de la formation et donc sa validité quand une formation de ce type est requise.

Comment: Si on ouvre un master qui n'est pas reconnu comme master, ce n'est pas un master, et donc on ne l'a pas ouvert...

Comment: Il y a deux aspects. 1/ Reconnu, par qui et pour quoi, avec quel effet pratique ?  P.e. on pouvait (on peut peut-être toujours) avoir un diplôme d'ingénieur en Belgique au titre légal ou au titre scientifique.  La différence était essentiellement administrative, il n'y avait un effet que si on cherche à rejoindre la fonction publique où le titre légal était nécessaire. En cas de changement d'orientation, faire des démarches pour faire reconnaître des équivalences était sensé, se prendre un an de retard pour repasser des cours parce que les équivalences n'étaient pas reconnues, moins.

Comment: 2/ Il est question ici d'être en cours d'accréditation, c'est-à-dire que le processus est commencé.  Ça peut être sensé de commencer la formation directement plutôt que d'attendre la fin du processus administratif. S'il suffit qu'il soit terminé avant la fin de la formation et si toutes les formations de l'établissement sont accréditées sauf celles qui viennent d'être proposées, gagner un an peut valoir le risque.  Si l'établissement n'a rien d'accrédité, par contre...

Comment: je suis d'accort avec toi @Unfrancophone car je suis déjà retenu pour ce master et je suis autorisé a m'inscrire, donc je pense pas que c'est une question d'ouverture du master, mais plutôt de reconnaissance

Comment: A mon avis, il s'agit d'une inscription à un master qui ouvrira sous réserve d'accréditation.  C'est à dire qu'on peut être candidat, être accepté, et se pré-inscrire, mais que la formation n'ouvrira effectivement que **si** la formation est accréditée.  Elle peut aussi être accréditée et ne pas ouvrir faute de candidats en nombre suffisant. C'est pour ça que les processus de sélection et de pré-inscription sont lancés dès que possible, parfois avant même l'accréditation qui conditionne l'ouverture.

Comment: Mais dans votre cas précis, au lieu de spéculer sur l'interprétation des mots, vous avez tout intérêt à demander au secrétariat de la formation - un simple courrier électronique suffira - pour demander si la formation va ouvrir. La réponse sera oui, non, ou ça dépend. Vous verrez bien. Ca sera plus probant que de poser la question sur stackexchange.